# what do the us, idh, idv stand for in the MCMCglmm in R

Tags: r, bayesian, variance, multi-level, random-effects

I am having hard time remembering the meaning of the us, idh, and idv functions in the MCMCglmm. I understand that these are the functions taking random variance-covariance structure into account, but are they abbreviations of some words in English? It would be helpful to know it to remember them and their underlying meaning. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `MCMCglmm` package in R, we have, from page 19 of the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMCglmm/MCMCglmm.pdf):

> `idv` fits a constant variance across all components in formula. Both
> `idh` and `us` fit different variances across each component in formula,
> but `us` will also fit the covariances.

As far as I know, none of `idh`, `idv,` or `us` are related to any particular statistical terms. In fact, I cannot find any references to these terms outside of the `MCMCglmm` package.

Comment: Hi，thank you very much for the quick response. I am sorry that I got obsessed with this thing, knowing the function without knowing the mean of the name makes mean uncomfortable for quite a long time already. The author name the function as idh, instead of 'ibm' (for instance), there had to be a reason... like 'aov' means 'analysis of variance'

Comment: I agree with @JustAMathematician.  I'm not aware of the terms being used anywhere outside of the package.  However, from the documentation, I'd guess that `idv` stands for "IDentical Variance" (the variance matrix is a multiple of the identity matrix), `us` stands for "unstructured" and `idh` comes from the oft-used (but not universal) notation that the prior for a parameter theta is denoted by h(theta): from the manual "idh ... fit[s] different variances across each component".  But I'm only guessing.  Particularly on the last one.